# about conditional operator in C# make variables are overflow

Tags: c#

The conditional operator do a overflow with variable.When I turn to "if...else...",everything goes well.why? Ridiculous...the result is *valueResult1=255,valueResult2=24,* The code goes as follows:

```
int valueInput1 =280;
byte valueResult1 =0;
if (valueInput1 > 255)
{
    valueResult1 = 255;
}
else if (valueInput1 < 0)
{
    valueResult1 = 0;
}
else
{
    valueResult1 = (byte)valueInput;
}

int valueInput2 =280;
byte valueResult2 =0;
valueResult2 = (byte) ( (valueInput2 > 255) ?  255 : (byte)valueInput2 );
valueResult2 =  (byte)((valueInput2 < 0) ?  0 : (byte)valueInput2);
```

Comment: What is not expected then? You're forcing(casting) an int > 255 to a byte!

Comment: Just curious why you're casting the `int`s to `byte`s. A byte can be no larger than 255.

Comment: it is imperative that the output variable must be byte...

Comment: Because your check on whether valueinput2 is less than 0 doesn't care about it being greater than 255, you're getting the overflow there. Your first ternary statement may as well not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is truncating the integer values by casting them to `byte`.

Try this...

```
int valueInput2 =280;
int valueResult2 =0;
valueResult2 = valueInput2 > 255 ? 255 : valueInput2;
valueResult2 = valueInput2 < 0 ? 0 : valueInput2;
```

Comment: Thank you,I change valueResult2's type into int,and tried your code ,now,the result shows valueResult2  = 280.....

Comment: No.  In the first line, you test whether `valueInput2` is greater than 255. It's value is 280, so it is greater than 255, so you set the value of `valueResult2` to 255.  Then in the next line, you test whether `valueInput2` is less than 0.  Since it's 255, it's not less than zero, and then you assign  `valueInput2` (which is still 280) to `valueResult2`.  So in the end, both `valueInput2` and `valueResult2` have the value of 280.    It's working exactly the way it's programmed.

Comment: Thanks for your patience.Got it ! I was a fool to have made this mistake!

Comment: No worries!  You're not alone - I've made silly mistakes plenty of times.